# Como chamar uma variável a partir de outras?

Tags: vba, variáveis, visual-basic-6

Minha intenção é que o código passe por 9 TextBox verificando se estão preenchidos com nomes ou vazios.

Para cada TextBox preenchido seria somado 1 em uma variável de contagem e seria alocado o texto do TextBox em outra variável (p1,p2,p3.....p9).

O problema é: como alocar o texto nas variáveis p, considerando o número final o mesmo número da variável de contagem?

Ex.:

```
Dim Cont As Integer
Dim P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9 As String

If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
   Cont = Cont + 1
   ("P"&Cont) = TextBox1.Text <<< Essa parte que não sei escrever
End If
```

A intenção no final é rodar um número aleatório entre 1 e a variável "cont" e selecionar aleatoriamente 3 nomes registrados nas variáveis P. Ou seja, depois seria necessário chamar as variáveis P pelo número que fosse encontrado pelo aleatório e registrar em algum label, etc.

Comment: Por que não cria um _array_ com estes nomes e depois procura pelo índices aleatoriamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que existem diversas opções para fazer o que pergunta, eu sugeriria utiliza um `Array` para isso, da seguinte forma:

```
Dim CAMPO As Control
Dim DADOS As Variant
Dim i As Integer

' Configura seu array com a quantidade de dados '9' no caso citado
ReDim DADOS(9, 2) As String

    i = 1

    For Each CAMPO In Me.Controls
        ' Verifica se é do tipo TextBox
        If TypeName(CAMPO) = "TextBox" Then

            ' Aqui pode-se verificar se 'CAMPO' está vazio e dar uma mensagem ao usuário, por exemplo
            ' if CAMPO = "" then
            '     MsgBox "ups"
            '     Exit Sub ' Ou Function...
            'End if

            DADOS(i, 1) = CAMPO.Name
            DADOS(i, 2) = CAMPO
        End If
     Next
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado Evert, eu ainda não sabia como utilizar arrays, mas o comentário do LINQ me fez pesquisar sobre o tema e sua resposta complementou com o que eu precisava para resolver o problema.

Nessas pesquisas, também verifiquei que dá pra colocar todos os textbox dentro de um frame e chamá-los na estrutura de array da seguinte forma: 

Frame1.Controls(0) <<< seria de zero até o número de elementos dentro do frame.

Obrigado a todos, me ajudaram muito! Abraços

Comment: Valeu!  Boa sorte aí!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode chamar a instância usando uma string:

```
Dim NameOfMyClass As String = "ConsoleApplication1.MyClassA"
Dim MyInstance As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(NameOfMyClass))
```